# Configuring cloudwatch alarm - alarm-actions option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm new to aws and I'm attempting to use the mon-put-metric-alarm command to create a monitor for my scaling group, my problem is I don't understand the alarm-actions option, which seems important.

I've seen this option used on a number of blogs and user guides but I have no idea where the values come from.

I've set up a launch config and auto scaling group, could you please point me in the right direction in finding out how I would determine the value of the alarm-actions option of the mon-put-metric-alarm command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I need to use the as-put-scaling-policy command.

Thanks.